# Adding a Teams Channel Using MS Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to create a channel using MS Graph within a BotFramework bot.  I get what appears to be a valid access Token.  However the code below generates the following error:

The collection type 'Microsoft.Graph.IChannelMembersCollectionPage' on 'Microsoft.Graph.Channel.Members' is not supported.

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var token = credential.GetToken(
    new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
        new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }));

var accessToken = token.Token;
Logger.LogWarning($"Token:{accessToken.ToString()}");
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage
        .Headers
        .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }));


try
{

    var chan = new Channel
    {
        DisplayName = $"Chan1",
        Description = "This channel is where we debate all future world domination plans",
        MembershipType = ChannelMembershipType.Standard
    };


    await graphServiceClient.Teams["{GroupID}"].Channels.Request().AddAsync(chan);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) or POSTMAN and is it working as expected?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to create channels in this team using Graph Explorer.  However this would be creating the channel based on my credentials.  I have enabled the following delegate permissions for my webapp that hosts the bot: Channel.Create
Channel.Delete.All
Channel.ReadBasic.All
openid
profile
User.Read

Answer (score 1):

You can use Graph SDK to generate token internally. Please try providing application permissions in azure portal and use the below code to create a channel in MS Teams. Below are the packages you need to install.

This is an example for application permissions. You can try the same code with minor changes/to no changes for delegate permissions.

[image]

```
           string clientId = "";
            string clientSecret = "1";
            string tenantId = "";
          
       

            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret) // or .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .Build();

            //AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);


            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var channel = new Channel
            {
                DisplayName = "Topic Discussion",
                Description = "This channel is where we debate all future architecture plans",
                MembershipType = ChannelMembershipType.Standard
            };

            await graphClient.Teams["{Your-teams-id}"].Channels
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(channel);
```

Comment: No Joy.  I get a new, terribly unhelpful exception:  UnknownError
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 date: 2021-01-25T19:47:32
 request-id: ebc7b3f9-f553-4583-b239-5eaee8caa0d0
 client-request-id: ebc7b3f9-f553-4583-b239-5eaee8caa0d0
ClientRequestId: ebc7b3f9-f553-4583-b239-5eaee8caa0d0    Any advice on how to debug an error like this?

Comment: @RichH: Can we connect over call to discuss this? Please write to us at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com